# How to render a partial and instance variable via ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Is it possible to render a partial and the model's data retrieved with just one ajax request?

```
# app/models/store.rb
def index
  user    = current_user;
  @stores = Store.where(:user_id => user.id)

  render :partial => "stores", :layout => false 
end

# app/views/stores/_stores.html.erb
<div class="stores">
  <select id="stores" class="dropdown">
    <% @stores.each do |store| %>
      <option value="<%= store.id %>"><%= store.name %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</div>

# app/views/users/index.html.erb
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url  : "/stores",

  success: function(data) {
    $("div").html(data); //rendering partial
    // how to get @stores variable??
  }
});
```

Imagining that @stores has 3 items from user with id = 1, how can I access this data on ajax success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using:

```
render :json => { :data => @stores, :stores => render_to_string(:partial => "stores") }
```

For now, I've @stores data and stores partial :)